# getting external media type

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

i would like to find a way detecting the type of the media in my optical drive (e.g. DVD+R, DVD-R, DVD-RW, CD+R, etc.) using a simple function in C++ on windows.

The function should not require Admin privilege.

**EDIT**

I implemented the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <imapi2.h>
#include <imapi2fs.h>
#include <imapi2error.h>
#include <imapi2fserror.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
IDiscFormat2Data*   discFormatData = NULL;
HRESULT hr;

       CoInitialize ( NULL );

hr = CoCreateInstance(  __uuidof(MsftDiscFormat2Data),
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_ALL,
    __uuidof(IDiscFormat2Data),
    (void**)&discFormatData);

if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
{        
    IMAPI_MEDIA_PHYSICAL_TYPE mediaType = IMAPI_MEDIA_TYPE_UNKNOWN; 

    hr = discFormatData->get_CurrentPhysicalMediaType(&mediaType);

    if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
    {
        std::cout << "MediaPhysicalType: " << mediaType << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::stringstream str;
        str << "get_CurrentPhysicalMediaType() failed with the error: 0x";

        str << std::hex << hr << ".";

        std::cout << str.str() << std::endl;


    }

    // Release the interface.
    // Tell the COM object that we're done with it.
    discFormatData->Release();
}
else
{
    std::stringstream str;
    str << "CoCreateInstance() failed with the error: 0x" << std::hex << hr;


    std::cout << str.str() << std::endl;
}

cin.get();

return 0;

}
```

at the moment my problem is that i get the following error: E_IMAPI_RECORDER_REQUIRED which means
"The request requires a current disc recorder to be selected."

Assuming i have at least two optical drivers, how can i differ between them?

Any ideas?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/505190/how-to-detect-current-media-type-in-cli-under-windows-dvd-rw-bd-r-etc

Comment: May be this helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows 2000 and later, you can use [`IOCTL_CDROM_GET_CONFIGURATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559334%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `SCSI_GET_CONFIGURATION_REQUEST_TYPE_CURRENT` flag to query an optical device for its current profile, which will tell you which type of disc (CD, DVD+-R/W, HDDVD, BluRay, etc) has been inserted, if any.  On earlier versions, you will have to manually send SCSI MMC commands directly to the device to query the same info.